# Trying to print all nodes as a string in a linked list, however it prints location instead

Tags: python, string, printing

Book Object with attributes: Title, Author, Year

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self, title = "", author = "", year = None):
        self.title = title
         self.author = author
    self.year = year

def getTitle(self):
    return self.title

def getAuthor(self):
    return self.author

def getYear(self):
    return self.year

def getBookDetails(self):
    string = ("Title: {}, Author: {}, Year: {}"\
                 .format(self.title, self.author, self.year))
    return string
```

Linked List called BookCollection

```
class BookCollection()
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    def insertBook(self, book)
       temp = BookCollectionNode(book)
       temp.setNext(self.head)
       self.head = temp

    def getAllBooksInCollection(self):
        node = self.head
```

Here is the issue below.  I amUsing a while loop to print each node, however its printing the  location of the node

```
        while node:
            print(node)
            node = node.next
```

Node class called BookCollectionNode

```
class BookCollectionNode():

    def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data
       self.next = None

    def getData(self):
       return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self, newData):
        self.data = newData
    
    def setNext(self, newNext):
        self.next = newNext
```

Using the functions below to print the nodes of the linked list

```
b0 = Book("Cujo", "King, Stephen", 1981)
b1 = Book("The Shining", "King, Stephen", 1977)
b2 = Book("Ready Player One", "Cline, Ernest", 2011)
b3 = Book("Rage", "King, Stephen", 1977)

bc = BookCollection()
bc.insertBook(b0)
bc.insertBook(b2)
bc.insertBook(b3)

print(bc.getAllBooksInCollection())
```

Comment: Please give full code so we can reproduce the problem, share Book class and insertBook method

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I edited the post to include the rest of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Fix

As node is a `BookCollectionNode`, you need to access it's `book` attribut, then call `getBookDetails()` method

```
def getAllBooksInCollection(self):
    node = self.head
    while node:
        print(node.data.getBookDetails())
        node = node.next
```

And call `bc.getAllBooksInCollection()` without the print. As there is no return statement, it returns `None` that you see printed

---

#### Improvements

1. It seems you don't really need methods to access your properties, but If you really want them, use `@property`

   ```py
   class Book:
       def __init__(self, title="", author="", year=None):
           self._title = title
           self._author = author
           self._year = year
       @property
       def title(self):
           return self._title
       @property
       def author(self):
           return self._author
       @property
       def year(self):
           return self._year
   ```
2. Override method `__str__` to get a builtin string when printing

   ```py
   class BookCollectionNode:
       def __str__(self):
           return str(self.data)

   class Book:    
       def __str__(self):
           return f"Title: {self._title}, Author: {self._author}, Year: {self._year}"
   ```
3. For `BookCollectionNode` getter/setter, the proper way is

   ```py
   class BookCollectionNode:
       def __init__(self, data):
           self._data = data
           self._next = None
       @property
       def data(self):
           return self._data
       @property
       def next(self):
           return self._next
       @data.setter
       def data(self, newData):
           self._data = newData
       @next.setter
       def next(self, newNext):
           self._next = newNext
   ```

Finally the `BookCollection` class becomes

```
class BookCollection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def insert_book(self, book):
        temp = BookCollectionNode(book)
        temp.next = self.head
        self.head = temp
    # 'print_' and not 'get_' as you don't return anything
    def print_all_books_in_collection(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            print(node)
            node = node.next
```

Comment: Yes that it! It prints all the nodes! However the last Node is None Type.  Why is that and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: @nwillows call `bc.getAllBooksInCollection()` without a print, because the method return nothing (so it returns the None you see)

Comment: That makes sense! I actually dont need to print the details for the get method function.  I just need to return the book details.  How can I store all the nodes through the while loop then return all the nodes at once?

Comment: @nwillows use a list ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you need to add a data argument to your constructor to get something like this:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

# Using an object of a Book with attributes: Title, Author, Year
b0 = Book("Cujo", "King, Stephen", 1981)
b1 = Book("The Shining", "King, Stephen", 1977)
b2 = Book("Ready Player One", "Cline, Ernest", 2011)
b3 = Book("Rage", "King, Stephen", 1977)

head = Node(b0, Node(b1, Node(b2, Node(b3))))


def print_list(head, end='\n'):
    while head:
        # You can extend the below logic
        print(head.data, end=' -> ' if head.next else '') 
        head = head.next
    print(end=end)


print_list(head)
```

Comment: You just implemented it a different way. The idea is to fix his code, not give another one . Please wait for further details in its code to find the error and fix it

Comment: Sorry. I accidently didn't share the rest of my code.  I edited the post now